# FabricJS - referencing after loading serialized canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, serialization, fabricjs

I serialize my canvas with the following code:

`var user_canvas = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessObject());`

All works fine. I then load the serialized canvas with the following code where 'serial' is the var for the serialized canvas:

`canvas.loadFromJSON(serial,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));`

All elements are displayed on the page as expected. From here though I cannot figure out how to reference these objects, `canvas.getObjects()` comes up as a blank array, however if I `console.log(canvas)` I can see the elements inside, I just cannot reference them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting a timeout of 5 seconds the items then appeared in `getObjects()`, it seems i was just trying to access them before they were loaded.

Edit: It turns out there is a callback function built into `canvas.loadFromJSON`

You can access the vars with the following:

`canvas.loadFromJSON(serialized_canvas,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),function(o, object) {
          console.log(object);
      }`